# Why, even after specifying a type parameter for a React component, the linter still complains about '<property>' missing in props validation?

Tags: typescript, react-native, type-parameter, typescript-eslint

Please consider the following TypeScript (`.tsx`) code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextInputProps } from 'react-native';
import { Container, TextInput, Icon } from './styles';

interface InputProps extends TextInputProps {
  name: string;
  icon: string;
}

const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({ name, icon, ...props }) => (
  <Container>
    <Icon name={icon} size={20} color="#666360" />

    <TextInput
      keyboardAppearance="dark"
      placeholderTextColor="#666360"
      {...props}
    />
  </Container>
);

export default Input;
```

By passing `TextInputProps` as a type parameter to `React.FC` I have access to the `TextInput` properties, which I'm destructuring in `...props`. But I also need `name` and `icon` for other purposes, so I created an interface extending `TextInputProps`, specified these properties there, and passed `InputProps` to `React.FC` instead.

Now I get `'name' is missing in props validation - eslintreact/prop-types` (same for 'icon'), but this didn't happen when I tried to get any of the properties specified inside `TextInputProps`.

Writing `const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({ name, icon, ...props }: InputProps) => (/*...*/);` makes the linter stop complaining, but I still don't get why using the type parameter doesn't.  Can someone clarify this to me? Am I getting some concept wrong, or is it just a problem with the linter?

PS: I'm writing this on VS Code with ESLint extension.

PS2: This is the code inside `styles.ts`, if it may help:

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import FeatherIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';

export const Container = styled.View`
  /* Some CSS */
`;

export const TextInput = styled.TextInput`
  /* More CSS */
`;

export const Icon = styled(FeatherIcon)`
  /* ... and CSS */
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, `eslint-plugin-react/prop-types` does not handle when the prop type is declared in the variable type annotation only.

The only test that they have that uses this syntax also explicitly types the `props` arg, which is probably why they haven't handled this case.

https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/72275716be7fb468fc9a2115603d9c1b656aa0da/tests/lib/rules/prop-types.js#L2578-L2599

Consider raising a bug in their repo https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react

Comment: So this is just a problem with eslint then? Not the typescript code itself.

Comment: correct - when VSCode shows you an error, it'll include an error code. This will help you figure out where it came from. In this example, the error code would have been `eslint(react/prop-types)`.

Answer (score 0):

`eslint-plugin-react@^7.25.0` has resolved this [issue](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/pull/3051)

So after the updates:

```
const Component: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {}
```

can be simplified to

```
const Component: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {}
```